# Exporting list of pandas dataframes to csv with list comprehension

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I wrote this list comprehension to export pandas Data Frames to CSV files (each data frame is written to a different file):

`[v.to_csv(str(k)+'.csv') for k,v in df_dict.items()]`

The pandas Data Frames are the values of a dictionary where the keys will be the part of the CSV file names. So in the code above `v` are the Data Frames, and `k` are strings to which the Data Frames are mapped to.

A colleague said that using list comprehensions is not a good idea for writing to output files. Why would that be? Moreover, he said that using a for loop for this would be more reliable. If true, why is that so?

Comment: I think it is no problem using `list comprehension` for looping, you write files by `to_csv` and agree it is more reliable.

Comment: You don't know what list comprehension does. You need to read [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). List comprehensions are a way of creating lists, not writing files. You need a proper loop to do what you are doing. Your colleague is correct.

Comment: Thanks to you both for your comments.

Comment: Although I have to say that the list comprehension works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A colleague said that using list comprehensions is not a good idea for writing to output files. Why would that be?

List comprehensions are usually more performant and readable than `for` loops when you are building a list (i.e., using `append` to generate a list with a `for` loop).

In other cases, like yours, a `for` loop is preferred when you want the "side effect" of an iteration.

> Moreover, he said that using a for loop for this would be more reliable. If true, why is that so?

A `for` loop is more readable and relevant for this use case, IMHO, and should therefore be preferred:

```
for k,v in df_dict.items():
    v.to_csv(str(k)+'.csv')
```

Comment: My pleasure! Thank you @ropolo